# Diagnostic Events Viewer in Visual Studio - how to configure

Tags: azure-service-fabric, etw

Question regarding the Diagnostic Events window (not the Diagnostic Tools window).

When running a service fabric project, the diagnostics event viewer appears.  I want to be able to add my own provider to this list rather than copy-paste the provider name of my service every time I hit f5.

For some reason while this is supposed to happen automatically, this window is not picking up my  provider (I think because my solution / project folders are not based off a classic "sln is in the root directory" organization - a hint about that is in the last post in this SO article: "[not logging to etw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323790/azure-servicefabric-samples-not-logging-to-etw)" ).

2 questions:

- how to set the list of providers automatically or through a config?
- Is there any documentation on this diagnostic events tool?

I have searched and not found any docs on the Diagnostic Events tool.  I am wondering if this is a service fabric extension tool and not a Visual Studio tool...

Thank you.
Mark

Answer (score 0):

For storing configuration, this is a feature request we are working on delivering in an update of the tooling. Currently this is not possible.

Comment: I have the same issue. Do you need physical folders' structure or solution's structure that is visible in Solution Explorer in VS?

Comment: Please share both - you can send an email to mikhegn(a) microsoft.com - thanks

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj sent.

Comment: Thanks for the information - we will be looking in to this bug.

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj the issue with not finding the providers is still happening. Was it addressed or was there some sort of recommendation? Thank you.

Comment: Soo long ago :-( Still an issue? What SDK version are you on?

Comment: I'm on SDK v2.8.232 and SF v6.8.232, and it's still happening. Note that other providers like 'Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Services' and 'Microsoft-ServiceFabric-Actors' are not being automatically added either. Perhaps the folder structure is causing an exception that is causing the code that scans for the [EventSource] attributes to exit prematurely?

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj this has been a major problem for me as it used to work. I'm not sure what update or change made this to stop working. Tried reinstalling VS, SF, ReSharper, etc. Only option left at this time to format which I can't do. How do I see what's causing it to not work..?
Using VS Enterprise 2017 15.5.2, Service Fabric 2.8.232.