# ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage doesn't show in Visual Studio Diagnostic Event window

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Out of the box the line

`ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");`

does not show up in my Diagnostic Window. The following execution always returns false in the **ServiceEventSource.cs**

```
this.IsEnabled()
```

However removing that check still shows nothing in the logs. I cannot output info using the generated class.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen this behavior when I open the Diagnostic Events window in Visual Studio before running the application on the local dev cluster. When I launch the application, VS opens another Diagnostic Events window.  Neither one of the windows receive any events while the application is running.  The only way to clear it is to restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by adding the EventSource in visual studio as per the correct answer here:

[Azure ServiceFabric samples not logging to ETW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35323790/azure-servicefabric-samples-not-logging-to-etw)